# Wp_options table in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a plugin for which I am saving the records in wp_options table using the below code.
This works fine for me. But while testing I noticed that at one point, the record was inserted in the wp_options table but the option_value column  went blank for some reason.

How do I handle a situation like this in my code. Because here what happens is even if there is a record in the table get_option function returns a blank  which in this case will make the if condition to get satisfied which will be incorrect.

```
$wp_form_setting =  get_option('wp_form_setting');
$jsonData = json_encode($_POST[frm_details])

if(empty($wp_form_setting )){  
             add_option('wp_form_setting',$jsonData);
         }else{  
             update_option('wpaf_apply_button',$jsonData);
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to tweak this a little.  You'll also want to make sure you are filtering the input data from the form.

```
$jsonData = json_encode($_POST[frm_details]);

if(get_option('wp_form_setting') === false) {  //check for existing option
    add_option('wp_form_setting',$jsonData);
} else { //option does exist, so update 
    update_option('wp_form_setting',$jsonData);
}
```